# In django how can I run a query that the values of (fielda, fieldb) are in an allowed set of pairs (1, 2), (3, 4)?

Tags: python, sql, django

In django how can I run a query that (fielda, and fieldb) are in an allowed set of pairs (1, 2), (3, 4)?
It doesn't look like this is possible using filter or Q queries. Is it?
Or do I need to do this with a raw sql query?

This is how one does it with a raw sql query: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/34266/selecting-where-two-columns-are-in-a-set

Comment: Does this query work `Model.objects.filter((Q(fielda=1) & Q(fieldb=2)) | (Q(fielda=3) & Q(fieldb=4)))`? If it does work then there are ways to generate it from a list of pairs dynamically

Comment: That should work. How about posting it as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can chain together as many Q objects as you like to create a series of conditions OR'd together.

An example where the pairs are already known:

```
Model.objects.filter(Q(fielda=1) & Q(fieldb=2) | Q(fielda=3) & Q(fieldb=4))
```

A more dynamic option to generate the query from an iterable is to create a Q object and then update it with additional conditions in a loop:

```
pairs = [(1, 2), (3, 4)]
query = Q()
for a, b in pairs:
    query |= Q(fielda=a) & Q(fieldb=b)
Model.objects.filter(query)
```